# Angular 2 X509 authentication from client to REST back-end

Tags: rest, angular, authentication, certificate, x509

I have a REST back-end that can be used based on X509 authentication using client certificate.

Now I have a front-end written in Angular 2 which should also use X509 authentication and further provide it to REST back-end.

What I do not understand is how to forward client certificate from Angular 2 front-end to REST back-end for authentication. Is it even possible or should I use one security domain as X509 authentication between front-end and client and second security domain as X509 authentication between front-end and back-end?

Comment: I have the same exact problem, did you manage to find the solution since?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Apache2 httpd server to host your Angular2 app, you can install mod_ssl on your system which varies depending on operating system.

After installing mod_ssl, a new config file is created. In my case it is located at: `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`. Place the following configuration, tweak for your use case of course.

You will need to have your CA cert, and a server cert signed by that CA as well as the server private key.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
         SSLEngine On
         SSLCertificateFile /var/www/html/certs/localhost.crt
         SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/html/certs/key.pem
         SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/html/certs/ca.crt
         SSLVerifyClient require
         SSLVerifyDepth 2
         SSLOptions +ExportCertData
         ServerAdmin info@example.com
         ServerName localhost
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html
         ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
         CustomLog /var/www/logs/access.log combined
         ProxyPass /services ajp://localhost:8009/services
         ProxyPassReverse /services ajp://localhost:8009/services
         SSLOptions +ExportCertData
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html
            <Directory /var/www>
                    Options -Indexes
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

After restarting apache2, it will now prompt the user for a certificate, and forward that certificate to the back-end thanks to the SSLOptions +ExportCertData